# Structure of the elements list in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to do a similar structure:

[image: view sample]

Which element is better to use in this case? ListView or something else? Each line must be clickable. "First Text", "Second Text" and "Third Text" will be added programmatically.

Comment: well if you are going to display a lot of items best option is listview. take a look here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Do you have a fixed and relatively small number of items? If so, it might be best to define your own vertical layout. Otherwise, use a listview with an adapter that serves up custom rows.

Comment: `ListView` for sure with a customized row ... There are thousands of articles on the web

Answer (score 3):

You should create your own view instead of using `listView` and you will need to customize adapter for this. Anyway [here is a nice implementation of this concept](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). I think it will help

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will need to create a list with a custom row, and a adapter. Take a [look at this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/). it should work